# How can I make the background color change when my character steps on a plane?

Tags: python, game-engine, world

I'm quite new in the blender world and am trying to create a small game. 
I try to make the background color change to a random color each time the character steps on a plane. However, I am having trouble thinking of how to go about doing this. What would be an easy way to do this in the game engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the background color via Python controller by calling [bge.render.setBackgroundColor()](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bge.render.html#bge.render.setBackgroundColor)